# SQL Delete with Join and Foreign Key constraint

Tags: sql, join, foreign-keys, constraints, delete-row

Using `10.0.31-MariaDB-1~jessie`.

I have two tables: `provider_contact` and `provider_contact_x_role` where `contact_id` column in `provider_contact_x_role` table has a foreign key reference to `id` column in `provider_contact` table.

When I run the following query the result is success:

```
DELETE cr, c
FROM provider_contact_x_role AS cr
INNER JOIN provider_contact AS c
ON cr.contact_id = c.id
WHERE c.is_test_contact = 0;
```

When i run next query:

```
DELETE cr, c
FROM provider_contact_x_role AS cr
INNER JOIN provider_contact AS c
ON cr.contact_id = c.id
WHERE c.email_address <> 'suren@test.com';
```

the result is the following error:

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(`ins_db`.`provider_contact_x_role`, CONSTRAINT 
`FK_contact_id--provider_contact.id` FOREIGN KEY (`contact_id`) 
REFERENCES `provider_contact` (`id`))
```

Note that the only difference between those two queries is the `WHERE` condition.

Questions:

1) Is there anything in SQL ensuring that when those queries are executed then the rows from the `provider_contact_x_role` are being deleted first ?

2) Any idea what makes a difference between those 2 queries (why 1st one succeeds and the 2nd one fails) ?

Comment: I think you need a cascading constraint on the foreign key definition.  What you are describing is data-dependent.

Comment: I know that it will work if I have cascading constraint but I want to understand this particular case (why 2nd query fails if the 1st one works)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extracted from MySQL documentation:

> If you use a multiple-table DELETE statement involving InnoDB tables
>   for which there are foreign key constraints, the MySQL optimizer might
>   process tables in an order that differs from that of their
>   parent/child relationship. In this case, the statement fails and rolls
>   back. Instead, you should delete from a single table and rely on the
>   ON DELETE capabilities that InnoDB provides to cause the other tables
>   to be modified accordingly.

And if you use `EXPLAIN` you will see that it prefers to first filter (and delete) by the main table as it need it to do the JOIN.

If you use an `INNER JOIN`, you could try `STRAIGHT_JOIN` which is the same as an `INNER JOIN` except that the left table is always read before the right table and put the tables in the order of deletion you want to achieve.

Alternatively to the cascade, you could disable the foreign keys in the delete statement with `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to delete first the records in your **provider_contact** table instead of **provider_contact_x_role** because it is enforcing the referential integrity from the **contact_id** foreign key.

```
DELETE c, cr
FROM provider_contact AS c
INNER JOIN provider_contact_x_role AS cr
ON c.id = cr.contact_id
WHERE c.email_address <> 'suren@test.com';
```

Comment: It's the exact opposite: records from `provider_contact_x_role ` should be deleted first, table `provider_contact_x_role ` has the foreign key

Comment: okay get it, so, why not just delete them in separate queries?

Comment: My problem is not to delete the rows somehow. I want to understand the reason why the 1st query works and the 2nd doesn't

Comment: What storage engine are you using? 
if the database is InnoDB you dont need to do joins in deletion. only
`DELETE FROM provider_contact WHERE email_address  <> 'email_address'` 

but if you are using MyISAM
proceed with your original SQL, 
because InnoDB has Row-Level locking, 
While MyISAM only has Table-Level Locking

Comment: @RanielleCanlas I don't think that is true for InnoDB if it doesn't have on delete cascade.